# How to find the smallest integer multiple of a rational number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Today in the news: "Under the deal, Credit Suisse shareholders will receive one UBS share for every 22.48 Credit Suisse shares.". So I was wondering what is the smallest number of Credit Suisse shares that one needs to have in order to not leave a fraction behind. I couldn't do better than going to WolframAlpha and ask for `solve(mod(x/22.48,1)=0,x)`, which gives me 562.

My question is: how would a mathematicion solve this without the use of a computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$22.48=\frac{2248}{100}=\frac{562}{25}$, so $\frac x{22.48}=\frac{25x}{562}$. For this to be an integer, the $x$ has to cancel out the $562$ in the denominator, so $x$ has to be a multiple of $562$. (We know the $25$ in the numerator doesn't help because $562$ and $25$ have no factors in common - that's why we reduced the fraction.)

Answer (score 1):

Write a rational number $x$ as $x=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb Z,b>o$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Then the smallest positive integer $m$ for which $mx$ is an integer is $m=b$. Note that if $x$ had been given in the form $x=\frac{c}{d}$ where $c,d \in \mathbb Z, d>0$, we could have calculated $a$ and $b$ by $\delta =\gcd(c,d), a=\frac{c}{\delta},b=\frac{d}{\delta}$ and the calculaion could be done in logarithmic time.